# Entity Framework como acceder al modelo de datos sin tener guardado las credenciales y configuraciones en el app.config

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2015, entity-framework

favor su colaboración con el siguiente problema:

Siempre trabaje con EF EDMX, al momento de crear el modelo suelo tickear las opciones "Si, incluir datos confidenciales en la cadena de conexión" y también el "Guardar configuración de conexiones en App.Config como:", pero en este caso en el que estoy debe hacerlo al contrario (sin tickear las dos opciones antes mencionadas), así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Bueno el modelo se genera con normalidad, pero ahora como cambio la cadena de conexión y como accedo a las tablas, vistas, procedures, etc???

Nota. La versión de EF es la 6.x

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0):

Yo uso esto en EF4:

En Modelo.Context.cs

```
public DataBaseEntities(string connectionString )
            : base(connectionString)
        {
        }
```

Donde DataBaseEntities es el nombre de tu entidad mediante la cual accedes a la BD.
connectionString es una cadena de conexión,yo la genero con EntityConnectionStringBuilder.